# using callback of node async parallel

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, node-async

I have few functions that can be executed in parallel. Using `async.parallel()` works fine, but it executes the main callback when an error is received.

As the functions are independent, I still want results from others even though on has error.

Here's my current code. Is there another `async` function for my need?

```
var async=require('async');
async.parallel({
    one:function(callback)
    {
        callback(null,1);
    },
    two:function(callback)
    {
        callback("ERROR Occured");
    },
    three:function(callback)
    {
        callback(null,3);
    },
    four:function(callback)
    {
        callback(null,4);
    }
},function(err,result)
{
    console.log(err);
    console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: If you do not call the callback with an error argument then final callback will not be called until all the functions are executed. Even if it is an error just call it with null as you are calling above. What is the problem?

Comment: I wanted to collect error messages too

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`reflectAll`](https://github.com/caolan/async#reflectalltasks):

```
var async = require('async');

async.parallel(async.reflectAll([
  function(callback) {
    callback(null,1);
  },
  function(callback) {
    callback("ERROR Occured");
  },
  function(callback) {
    callback(null,3);
  },
  function(callback) {
    callback(null,4);
  }
]), function(err,result) {
  console.log(err);
  console.log(result);
});
```

How this works is explained [here](https://github.com/caolan/async#reflectfunction):

> Wraps the function in another function that always returns data even when it errors. The object returned has either the property `error` or `value`.

Comment: Its a good alternative, but I'll have to perform additional operations to extract the `value` of `error` for each object and form another array with my keys like `one` `two` `three` along with values and errors.

Instead of doing all that, I might just use an array in outer scope and push the errors in it